# IMDb web scrapping errors: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' and ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am practicing web scraping of movie data from IMDb. for each movie, I want to extract and save on a dataframe: movie title, year, age rating (PG), rating, number of votes, stars/casts, and description. however, I've been stuck because of these couple of errors:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

my code:

```
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?user_rating=6.9,10.0&adult=include&count=250'
response = get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', 'lister-item mode-advanced')

first_movie = movie_containers[0]

first_movie_name = first_movie.h3.a.text
first_movie_name
first_movie_year = first_movie.h3.find('span', 'lister-item-year text-muted unbold')
first_movie_year.text
first_movie_PG = first_movie.find('span', 'certificate')
first_movie_PG.text
first_movie_rating = float(first_movie.strong.text)
first_movie_rating
first_movie_votes = first_movie.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})
first_movie_votes.text
first_movie_genre = first_movie.find('span','genre')
first_movie_genre.text
first_movie_runtime = first_movie.find('span', 'runtime')
first_movie_runtime.text
first_description = first_movie.find_all('p', {"class":"text-muted"})[1].text.strip()
first_description
first_stars = [s.text for s in first_movie.select('a[href*="name"]')]
first_stars

#storing scraped data in list

movie_title = []
year = []
age_rating = []
movie_genre = []
imdb_rating = []
votes = []
movie_casts = []
movie_description = []

#extracting data from individual movie container

for container in movie_containers:
    name = container.h3.a.text
    movie_title.append(name)
    
    year = container.h3.find('span', 'lister-item-year text-muted unbold').text
    year+year
    
    age_rating = container.find('span', 'certificate').text 
    age_rating+age_rating
    
    genre = container.find('span','genre').text
    movie_genre.append(genre)
    
    rating = float(container.strong.text)
    imdb_rating.append(rating)
    
    votes = container.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'}).text
    votes+votes
    
    casts = [s.text for s in container.select('a[href*="name"]')]
    movie_casts+casts
    
    description = container.find_all('p', {"class":"text-muted"})[1].text.strip()
    movie_description.append(description)
```

this is where i got the first error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [46], in <cell line: 12>()
     16 year = container.h3.find('span', 'lister-item-year text-muted unbold').text
     17 year+year
---> 19 age_rating = container.find('span', 'certificate').text 
     20 age_rating+age_rating
     22 genre = container.find('span','genre').text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

then i decided to comment the lines 19 and 20 where the error seem to be coming from and proceeded with the following code:

```
# creating movie dataframe

import pandas as pd
movie_df = pd.DataFrame({'movie':movie_title,
                        'year of production':year,
                        'imdb rating':imdb_rating,
                        'number of imdb votes':votes,
                        'genre':movie_genre,
                        'casts':movie_casts,
                        'movie description':movie_description
                       })
movie_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(movie_df, orient='index')
print(movie_df)
```

and this is where i got the second error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [47], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 movie_df = pd.DataFrame({'movie':movie_title,
      3                         'year of production':year,
      4                         'imdb rating':imdb_rating,
      5                         'number of imdb votes':votes,
      6                         'genre':movie_genre,
      7                         'casts':movie_casts,
      8                         'movie description':movie_description
      9                        })
     10 movie_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(movie_df, orient='index')
     11 print(movie_df)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:636, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    630     mgr = self._init_mgr(
    631         data, axes={"index": index, "columns": columns}, dtype=dtype, copy=copy
    632     )
    634 elif isinstance(data, dict):
    635     # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 636     mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    637 elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    638     import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:502, in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    494     arrays = [
    495         x
    496         if not hasattr(x, "dtype") or not isinstance(x.dtype, ExtensionDtype)
    497         else x.copy()
    498         for x in arrays
    499     ]
    500     # TODO: can we get rid of the dt64tz special case above?
--> 502 return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:120, in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    117 if verify_integrity:
    118     # figure out the index, if necessary
    119     if index is None:
--> 120         index = _extract_index(arrays)
    121     else:
    122         index = ensure_index(index)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:674, in _extract_index(data)
    672 lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    673 if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 674     raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
    676 if have_dicts:
    677     raise ValueError(
    678         "Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering."
    679     )

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

I understand the second error is because the length of the lists are not the same so I typed the following code to check the length of each list

```
print(len(movie_title), len(year), len(movie_genre), len(imdb_rating), len(votes), len(movie_casts), len(movie_description))
```

and got the output:

```
250 8 250 250 6 0 250
```

going through the website, I realize that each movie has 'year', 'votes' and 'stars' so why am I getting 8, 6, and 0 respectively instead of 250 for each?
any idea how I can solve these errors?
thanks

Comment: may be this useful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72942742/6593287

Comment: thanks a lot, @SergeyK. looks promising.

Comment: @SergeyK source = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?user_rating=6.9,10.0&adult=include&count=250") I got the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'. Any idea how to resolve this? also, how can I scrape movie stars and movie PGs?

Comment: @SergeyK hello? any suggestion, please?